# How to suppress clang-tidy warnings from thirdparty though cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake, clang-tidy

I want to see warnings only from `/src` directory, and don't see from `thirdparty`.

I write the next commands

```
set_target_properties(lolkeklol PROPERTIES CXX_CLANG_TIDY
                      clang-tidy;-checks=-*;-warnings-as-errors=-*,clang-*,performance*,bugprone-*)
```

Also i have `.clang-tidy` file in witch i have the same setting as above. The target have all libraries from thirdparty, and i can't split it to several targets.

Comment: sorry `wont -> want`

Comment: you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62893857/edit) your question to fix typos. How are you running `clang-tidy`? Please show a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles i did it)